# Find min of max in less time complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I am looking at this code challenge:

> Given an `array` of integers and another integer `m`.
>
> Choose an integer between `0` and `m`, and replace occurrences of `0` in input array of integers with this integer, then check the absolute difference between adjacent array items.
>
> Find the maximum absolute difference in each case. Then **finally** find the `minimum` of all those maximums.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> array = [4,0,3,2]
> m = 2;
> ```
>
> **Expected output:**
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> - select i=0, replace all occurrences of 0 in the array with the value of i that is 0 in this case: [4,0,3,2]. Find the absolute difference between adjacent elements [4-0, 3-0, 3-2] = [4,3,2]. Maximum among these absolutes is 4.
> - select i=1, replace all occurrences of 0 in the array with the value of i that is 1 in this case: [4,1,3,2]. Find the absolute difference between adjacent elements [4-1, 3-1, 3-2] = [3,2,1]. Maximum among these absolutes is 3.
> - select i=2, replace all occurrences of 0 in the array with the value of i that is 2 in this case: [4,2,3,2]. Find the absolute difference between adjacent elements [4-2, 3-2, 3-2] = [2,1,1]. Maximum among these absolutes is 2.
> - Finally, the minimum of all maxima is min(4,3,2) = 2, which is the answer.
>
> **constraints:**
>
> - `array` has 1 to 10<sup>5</sup> items
> - `array[i]` ranges from 0 to 10<sup>9</sup>
> - `m` ranges from 0 to 10<sup>9</sup>

This is my code:

```
static int solve(List<Integer> list, int m) {
    int response = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int n = list.size();
    for(int i=0; i<=m ;i++) {
        int j = list.get(0);
        int max = 0;
        if(j==0) j = i;
        for(int k=1; k<n; k++) {
            int e = list.get(k);
            if(e==0) e = i;
            int abs = Math.abs(e-j);
            max = Math.max(max, abs);
            j = e;
        }
        response = Math.min(response, max);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Time complexity of this code is `O(m*n)`.

What is the correct approach to solve this problem to reduce the time complexity?

Comment: if a web page is the source of this problem, please provide a link to that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your array once, finding the max and min of all elements that are not zero, but that are adjacent to a zero.

The ideal answer is (max + min) / 2, rounding either way.

If this is bigger than m, choose m, otherwise choose this.

Comment: This gets the min max you can affect. The min max of the input may be due to a pair of adj elts neither of which is 0. e.g. [0,1,100]

Comment: For input [5,0,0,0,4] and m = 10, the correct answer is 1. But using this approach max element is 5 and min element is 4. So the result is (5+4)/2 = 4. But expected result is 1. can you please check if I am missing anything in understanding your answer.

Comment: @technotigr Why 1? With 1, the max difference is 5-1=4; with 4 it's 5-4=1.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas one I am sure will work but doesn't improve your time complexity much and one that may need testing to make sure it does what you want.

method 1 (the faster but may not do what you want): On the first run (when i is zero and zeroes are not replaced) take the differences as normal (I will refer to the max difference of this run as MaxNoReplace) but record the least number neighboring a zero (LeastZeroNeighbor) and the max difference between non-zero items (MaxDiffNonZeroNeighbors). if the max difference between non-zero neighboring items equals the max difference overall then return max difference between non-zero items (the max difference isn't going to get any lowest since it doesn't depend on what you replace zero with) else return the min of the max of difference the least number neighboring a zero and m and the max difference between non-zero neighboring item and MaxNoReplace or min(max(m-LeastZeroNeighbor, MaxDiffNonZeroNeighbors),MaxNoReplace)

method 2 (slower but I am sure (surer) it will work): On the first run (when i is zero and zeroes are not replaced) take the differences as normal but note where the zeros are and keep the max difference between non-zero items. On all other runs only compute the difference the now replaced zeros and it neighbors, if none of those are greater than the max difference between non-zero items that return that as the max instead. Take the min of max as normal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).